# Ubuntu 12.10 graphics card error

Tags: 12.10, intel-graphics

Since Ubuntu 12.10 I have an error with the video card. My graphics card is "Intel HD graphics".
The screen is distorted and sometimes there appear error messages.

[image]
Because Ubuntu does not recognize the graphics card, I installed mesa-utils. Now appears that I am using Intel ® Sandy Bridge desktop, but the errors are still on.

[image]

---

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 once again and this time I've made ​​no updates. Now there are no more errors. The problem must be due to the updates. Because I have to do about 300 updates, it will be difficult to pick out the faulty one.

---

With Synaptic I made updates stepwise and have now localized the faulty package. Incorrectly could be one of the following packages:

> Commit Log for Sat Mar 30 12:25:05 2013
>
> Die folgenden Pakete wurden entfernt: (The following packages were removed:)
>   libdrm-intel1:i386
>   libdrm-nouveau2:i386
>   libdrm-radeon1:i386
>   libdrm2:i386
>   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
>   libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
>   libglu1-mesa:i386
>   playonlinux
>   wine
>   wine1.4
>   wine1.4-amd64
>   wine1.4-common
>   wine1.4-i386:i386
>
> Die folgenden Pakete wurden aktualisiert:(The following packages have been updated:)
>   alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu3) to 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1
>   app-install-data-partner (12.12.10) to 12.12.10.1
>   apport (2.6.1-0ubuntu3) to 2.6.1-0ubuntu10
>   apport-gtk (2.6.1-0ubuntu3) to 2.6.1-0ubuntu10
>   apt (0.9.7.5ubuntu5) to 0.9.7.5ubuntu5.4
>   dmsetup (2:1.02.74-4ubuntu1) to 2:1.02.74-4ubuntu1.1
>   libcairo-gobject2 (1.12.2-1ubuntu2.2) to 1.12.4-0ubuntu0~quantal15.2
>   libcairo2 (1.12.2-1ubuntu2.2) to 1.12.4-0ubuntu0~quantal15.2
>   libdevmapper-event1.02.1 (2:1.02.74-4ubuntu1) to 2:1.02.74-4ubuntu1.1
>   libdevmapper1.02.1 (2:1.02.74-4ubuntu1) to 2:1.02.74-4ubuntu1.1
>   libdrm-intel1 (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) to 2.4.40-0ubuntu0~quantal5.2
>   libdrm-nouveau1a (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) to 2.4.40-0ubuntu0~quantal5.2
>   libdrm-nouveau2 (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) to 2.4.40-0ubuntu0~quantal5.2
>   libdrm-radeon1 (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) to 2.4.40-0ubuntu0~quantal5.2
>   libdrm2 (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) to 2.4.40-0ubuntu0~quantal5.2
>   libkms1 (2.4.39-0ubuntu1) to 2.4.40-0ubuntu0~quantal5.2
>   libva1 (1.0.15-4build1) to 1.1.0-0ubuntu0~quantal5.1
>   linux-image-generic (3.5.0.17.19) to 3.5.0.26.32
>   linux-libc-dev (3.5.0-17.28) to 3.5.0-26.42
>   ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.2.71) to 1:0.2.71.1
>   xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.20.9-0ubuntu2) to 2:2.20.12-0ubuntu0~quantal5.1
>
> Die folgenden Pakete wurden installiert:(The following packages were installed:)
>   linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic (3.5.0-26.42)

Comment: Could you put some translations there?

Comment: I have same problem with 12.10.
Problem in kernel update. I use grub to loading ubuntu with 3.5.0-17 generic kernel after all updates and graphics works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the following packages and now it works.

```
linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic (3.5.0-26.42)  
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-26-generic (3.5.0-26.42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source ia32-libs mesa-utils
```

Comment: I get the following errror:  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.